# Determine whether a thunk request is pending

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

I have a React application that consumes a REST API and stores the data to redux. I'm trying to cut down on boilerplate when pulling from new endpoints, so I'm working on a wrapper around redux toolkit's `createAsyncThunk` method and a method to generate my `extraReducers` components. Additionally I have a method that wraps my API requests to provide auth. Some of my components such as my OAuth callback dispatch an action when the component mounts.

My problem is that duplicate actions are dispatched because I don't know when a request has been sent. I know I can use `useState` to track when something has been sent on the component side, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution. Is there a common design pattern for this use case?

The relevant code is shown below:

```
  // wrapper around data returned from API
  export interface AsyncState<T> {
    status: RequestStatus,
    value: T,
    error: Error | string
  }
  
  // wrapper around API requests to provide an authenticated axios client
  export const authRequest =
    <ActionReturnType, ActionArgumentType=null>(method: (params: ActionArgumentType & {client: AxiosInstance}) => Promise<ActionReturnType>) =>
      async (param: ActionArgumentType, thunkAPI): Promise<ActionReturnType> => {
        const state = thunkAPI.getState()
        if (!state.##MY_AUTH_PATH##) {
          throw new Error(`auth not set`)
        }
        const token = `Bearer ${state.##MY_AUTH_PATH##}`
        const client = axios.create({
          headers: {
            Authorization: token
          },
        })

        const data = await method({
          ...param,
          client
        })
        return data
      }

  // method run in 'extraReducers' part of slice creation
  export const makeAsyncReducer = <
    ActionReturnType, // type returned from async action
    ActionArgumentType, // type of argument passed to async action
    SliceState // the type of state of the reducer combiner
  >(
    builder: ActionReducerMapBuilder<SliceState>,
    action: AsyncThunk<ActionReturnType, ActionArgumentType, AsyncThunkConfig>,
    formatValue: (state: Draft<SliceState>, v: ActionReturnType) => DeepPartial<Draft<SliceState>>
  ) => {
    builder.addCase(action.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state = ObjectUtils.mergeDeep(
        state,
        formatValue(state, action.payload)
      )
      return state
    })
    builder.addCase(action.pending, (state, action) => {
      // unsure of how to implement
    })
    builder.addCase(action.rejected, (state, action) => {
      state = ObjectUtils.mergeDeep(
        state,
        _.chain({})
          .set(`${action.error.state_key}.status`, RequestStatus.Rejected)
          .set(`${action.error.state_key}.value`, null)
          .set(`${action.error.state_key}.error`, action.error.error)
          .value()
      )
      return state
    })
  }
// example action
export const getMe = createAppAsyncThunk(
  'profile',
  authRequest(API.getMe)
)

const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'api',
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder.addCase(setChallenge, (state, action) => {
      const c = current(state)
      const updated = ObjectUtils.mergeDeep(c, {
        auth: {
          value: {
            challenge: action.payload
          }
        }
      })
      return updated
    })
    makeAsyncReducer(builder, exchangeCode, (state, response) => {
      return ObjectUtils.mergeDeep(state, {
        auth: {
          status: RequestStatus.Fulfilled,
          value: response
        }
      })
    })
    makeAsyncReducer(builder, getMe, (state, response) => {
      return ObjectUtils.mergeDeep(state, {
        profile: {
          value: response
        }
      })
    })
  }
})
```

Thanks!

Comment: You might be recreating `createApi`, which ships with Redux Toolkit here. Are you aware that RTK Query exists? https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview

Answer (score 3):

RTK's `createApi` ended up being the solution

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).